# fetch records one by one from each category in the table

Tags: mysql

table structure is as following.

```
item_id, item_name, dealer_id
```

this table has a lot of number of records. Having different number of records for different dealer.

in the item list , there are all the items having paging.
but i want to show all item on a page from different dealers. if there are no more items for unique dealers then it can show multiple items for same dealer.

how can i get this ?

table data is as following :

```
ITEM_ID  ITEM_NAME DEALER_ID
1        a         215
2        b         500
3        c         517
4        d         215
5        e         518
6        f         517
7        g         215
8        h         565
9        i         517
10       j         215
11       k         500
12       l         247
13       m         215
14       n         530
15       o         517
16       p         215
17       q         500
```

I want them in following order - it is sorted on dealer id.

```
ITEM_ID  ITEM_NAME DEALER_ID
1        a         215    
12       l         247
2        b         500    
3        c         517     
5        e         518
14       n         530    
8        h         565   
16       p         215    
17       q         500    
9        i         517     
7        g         215    
11       k         500
15       o         517
13       m         215 
6        f         517     
4        d         215    
10       j         215
```

although it is sorted on dealer but in the result set first look for items from different dealers. if there are no more items from different dealers then it can have from same dealer.

Comment: It'll be really beneficial to put up an example of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to tell what you want, but I *think* it might be this:

```
select ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, DEALER_ID
from mytable
order by ITEM_NAME, DEALER_ID
```

Comment: suppose, i want to sort them on dealer_id but at the same time items from same dealer should be together. as i dont want to show only some dealer's item on the item list.
as if there are more items from same dealer then there is less chance to show other dealer's items on the top of list.
i want to give equal chance to all dealers to show their items.
i hope it must be clear now.